# iOS Simulator build error after upgrade Flutter 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, dart

Today, I upgrade my project version from 3.3.x to 3.7.0. and it has error below.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             13.0s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           131.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

How can I solve this problem... can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre`

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 
'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and
 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
```

Hide all conflicting classes that you don't use, so that the Compiler
only sees the class it should use.

```
import 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart';
```

or

Use "as" keyword to provide the name to the class you want to use.
Then use this name as a prefix of the class.

```
import 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' as otherName;
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart';
```

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i solved temporary by updating modal bottom sheet pubspect.yaml as per modal bottom sheet github pull request.